ときとかも: What does it mean

The character is recalling his childhood and how he was  fan of a certain band. Buecase he was in middle school he couldn't take part in the live.
What I'm stumbled, is what is the second set of bubbles trying to say? ときとかも  is 時+?

とか adds a sense of "and such" or "among others".

対バンの時
at the time of the taiban
対バンの時も
also at the time of the taiban
対バンの時とかも
also at times such as the taiban
also when there's a taiban and similar occasions

(Note: 対バン today usually means "joint show" or "double-bill live", but it may involve competition or more than two bands. Choose the appropriate translation according to the context.)
